# Can I get Doxygen to merge namespace contents in different files?

Tags: c++, doxygen

I have different .h files that each provide declarations in the same namespace. Doxygen generates a new entry for each file, with the same name. Can I make doxygen to merge all these?

Comment: Are the declaration in the different .h files of the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

Add at least one documented namespace declaration. I'm using to do this in a separate header file, that contains documentation global definitions (main page, groups, etc.) for the project's root namespace.